# matlab cell contents , how to tell what they are?

Tags: arrays, matlab, hex, cell

I have a cell array, c, filled with hexadecimal data and when I view the cell contents by typing c at the matlab prompt, it shows me contents enclosed between ticks, i.e., '0x0009'.   But, one element is enclosed in brackets and looks like [650345].  How can I convert the [ ] data to ' ' data?  When I do iscellstr on this particular element, matlab returns 0. iscellstr returns 1 for all other elements of c.

I'm reading this data into matlab from excel and I fear that excel 'helped' me by converting one hex value to scientific notation.  I can't, as far as I've found, change what excel did. I think the true value is lost and unrecoverable. But I need to convert this one outstanding value, even if incorrect, to be like the other cell values so that I can carry on with my processing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `['0x',dec2hex(650345)]` is the correct value?

Comment: Is that `650345` a decimal number that you need to convert to hexadecimal number and store it at that location as a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of wrong value and it's true value, you just do:

```
c(idx) = {'0x0009'};
```

Comment: I have too much data and can't manually look up the true value of the element in question and type it in like this.  How would I use the notation of c{row,col} in your suggested notation? Sprintf?

Comment: I've come up with this soln so far:  I'm finding the 'problem' entries by using iscellstr on the cells:  iscellstr(c(r)) where r is some index.  Then at indices where iscellstr returns a zero, I convert the cell contents to str using num2str(c{z}), where z is the index of the element that returned zero from iscellstr. This can be automated to 'fix' the data wherever it occurs without hands on searching and parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
ind = cellfun(@isnumeric, c); %// find numeric cells
c(ind) = cellfun(@(s) ['0x' dec2hex(s)], c(ind), 'uniformout', 0); %// convert to
%// hex string and prepend '0x'
```

Example: input

```
c = {'0x0009', 650345};
```

produces the output

```
c = 
'0x0009'    '0x9EC69'
```